# como exportar excel a partir de un array en angular

Tags: angular, excel, exportar

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

this.reversionesService.getReversionesExportarSeguimiento(this.solicitud).subscribe(res => {
console.log('Se exporto correctamente');
this.respuestaExportar=res;

var fileData = JSON.stringify(this.respuestaExportar.archivoExcel, undefined, 4);
var exportar = new Blob([fileData],{type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(exportar);
window.open(objectUrl);

donde archivoExcel es un array, lo que deseo es convertirlo a excel y lo abra automaticamente, en que estaria fallando ya que no se puede abrir el excel, o existe otra manera mas práctica de descargar el archivo EXCEL, gracias.

Comment: Me sospecho que por seguridad, no te dejara abrirlo automáticamente.

Comment: lo que quiero es que se descargue el archivo en formato excel a partir de byte[] an angular

Comment: Puede que esto te sirva: https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857